# Newbie freelancer, advice needed

Tags: freelance-websites

I'm a webdeveloper, who want to start freelancing. I tried the following sites without any

- Freelancer.com

  - Tried it for several months and I got only one "job".
  - I got a bad client who quitted after accepting the job. It was a hard round to get my money back.
- Upwork

  - Trying it for several months without any jobs.
- Peopleperhour

  - I registered half year ago as a freelancer, but I got a "recruiter" registration and I can't post new hourly or bid on jobs.

What do you advise?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally very competitive to land yourself a freelancing job. If you don't have a very impressive portfolio, you are out of luck. Nobody will give you easy access to well-paying clients.

My best advise is for you to do something for yourself. Don't wait and don't rely on your "bad" clients. Build your portfolio, meet people and go from there. Don't waste time on those websites, just start your own business. Once you have a business running, you should get to know the community, and by then your personal connection will land you well-paid jobs.

Most of the good contracting jobs **are not done online**, they are by personal contacts. People will trust you more if they know what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar experience: almost impossible together jobs at upwork. But I have succeeded at PeoplePerHour.  My advice is that you try with a regular account there. I'm getting a constant stream of jobs, and the pay is increasing.